# Java: Getting a substring from a string starting after a particular String

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string:

```
CLAIM NUMBER 1234563 AND INCIDENT DATE 12/12/2020 12:00:00
```

I would like to extract `1234563` and `12/12/2020 12:00:00` from this, i.e. the substring after the NUMBER and DATE.

Could someone please provide some help?

I tried though the the substring and index but it's not giving expected answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show the code you tried?

Comment: You could `split` that `String` by (an arbitrary amount of) whitespace(s) and simply take indexes 2, 6 and 7 from the resulting `String[]`. That will only reliably work with this `String` or, more generally, ones of this very form.

Comment: Perhaps [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) is appropriate?

Comment: yes i applied the regular expression ^CLAIM_NUMBER (.*) AND INCIDENT_DATE (.*)$ and i got the solution thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to use regexp to extract data from formatted string.

```java
final String regex = "CLAIM NUMBER\\s+(?<claimNumber>\\S+)\\s+AND INCIDENT DATE\\s+(?<incidentDate>\\S+\\s+\\S+)";
final String str = "CLAIM NUMBER 1234563 AND INCIDENT DATE 12/12/2020 12:00:00";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if(matcher.matches()) {
    String claimNumber = matcher.group("claimNumber");
    String incidentDate = matcher.group("incidentDate");
}
```

Comment: thank you @oleg.cherednik I used the same code its perfect for my problem

Answer (score -1):

If the text is always the same, then you can do that with `String#substring()`.

```
String data = "CLAIM NUMBER 1234563 AND INCIDENT DATE 12/12/2020 12:00:00 ";
String number = data.substring(13, 20);
String datetime = data.substring(39, 58);
System.out.println(number + ", " + datetime);
// output: 1234563, 12/12/2020 12:00:00
```

Comment: @SEETHARAMUGN Is this what you have been looking for?